# Sun overhead in Barbados

Tags: geography

The sun is directly overhead in Barbados twice a year, my guess is approx 5-6th May and 5-6th August. What are the exact dates?

Comment: Find the latitude of the Barbados (or where-ever) and see when the sun's declination is equal to that latitude using something like HORIZONS: https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/app.html or WebGeoCalc https://wgc.jpl.nasa.gov:8443/webgeocalc/#NewCalculation or any astronomy software

Comment: A more general question (which might already have an answer) is "how do I compute on which days, if any, the Sun is overhead at a given location?"

Comment: please take a look here https://www.timeanddate.com/ they have the answer to your question and a lot more.